# Altera valor de um array em VUE filtrando por outro parametro

Tags: javascript

tenho o seguinte array em VUE:

```
acoes : [
            { name: 'Quero Vender', id:'quero-vender', active: false },
            { name: 'Quero Comprar', id:'quero-comprar', active: true },

            ] ,
```

estou passando o campo id da array para uma função eu preciso que seja setado o campo active como true do registro onde o ID é 'quero-comprar', como posso fazer?

Comment: Sua pergunta é boa, mas precisa de mais detalhes. Poderia fornecer? posso te ajudar...

Comment: Sem informação suficiente não dá pra saber o que você precisa. [Essa sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/350074/6333) já resolve seu problema, mas acredito que seja um [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/6333). O que você quer fazer e o que você já tentou?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não conheço nada de Vue mas sua dúvida é mais sobre JS do que Vue.

Você pode usar um [ARRAY MAP](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
O `Array map` irá retornar um novo array com as modificações que você desejar, neste caso, para cada item do array eu modifico o atributo active verificando se o valor é 'quero-comprar' e retorno o próprio item.

```
methods: {
  funcaoManeira: function ($arr) {
      reuturn $arr.map(function($a){ 
           $a.active = $a.id == 'quero-comprar';
           return $a;
      })
  }
}
```