# Como remover item de um array filtrando pelo valor?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tenho um determinado array:

```
acoes_selecionadas: ['nome1', 'nome2'];
```

Estou usando essa função, porem o `splice` funciona baseada no ID do elemento, preciso encontrar uma forma de remover pelo valor.

```
seta_vender: function() {
    this.vender = !this.vender;
    if (this.vender) {
        this.acoes_selecionadas.push('Vender');
    } else {
        this.acoes_selecionadas.splice('Vender');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar [JavaScript Array indexOf() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) para encontrar o índice do valor e remover o elemento da lista usando splice(como mencionou na pergunta). Nesse exemplo dá pra passar diretamente o índice passando no `v-for`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    acoes_selecionadas: ['nome1', 'nome2']
  },
  methods: {
    seta_vender(valor) {
      var indice = this.acoes_selecionadas.indexOf(valor)
      this.acoes_selecionadas.splice(indice , 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <div id='app'>
    <ul>
      <li v-for='valor in acoes_selecionadas' @click='seta_vender(valor)'>
        {{valor}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, eu usaria a função [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) do javaScript.

Dando uma explicação básica, ela faz a interação com seu array, e quando a condição imposta é verdadeira, ela retorna o elemento, já o concatenando de volta ao array. Quando é falso, o elemento não é retonado.

```
seta_vender : acoes_selecionadas.filter((val) => {
   return vender != val;
});
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Edit: Alteração na lógica, conforme comentado pelo Anderson.

Comment: Acredito que no caso a condição seria invertida, `vender !== val`, pois ele quer remover o  elemento. Além disso, há a questão de se existir elementos duplicados. O `filter` irá remover todos, mas talvez isso não seja o desejado - seria bom questionar o AP sobre isso.

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de procurar o índice do elemento a cada clique, você pode usar o [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-for) com índices:

```
<li v-for="(valor, index) in valores" @click="remove(i)">
```

Fica mais simples, rápido e direto.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    valores: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5']
  },
  methods: {
    remove: function(i) {
      this.valores.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(valor, index) in valores" @click="remove(index)">
      {{ valor }} ({{ index }})
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```